# form component inside another form in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have a a big form in a componentA

inside componentA at some point, I call a componentB.

componentB contain some stuff, and also a form.

when I submit componentA form, I submit componentB form.

I can check the error and invalid/required input there but, I wish to disable the button to send the form if componentA form or componentB form has invalids value.

How can I achieve that? I have a relation beetween the component, so do I make a custon "isvalid" function on component A checking booth forms ?

Answer (score 0):

did you use Input & Output annotations for passing data and flags to disable and enable buttons and getting values?

if yes, you can make a single submit button in the last step in your logic and sharing global object if they related.
 I suggested your logic will in one component.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use one HTML form like this :

```
<form name="myForm">
  <componentA>
    <componentB></componentB>
 </componentA>
</form>
```